# Getting an error "unable to resolve class org.jfree.util.Log grails" after upgrading grails from 1.3.x to 2.0.4

Tags: grails, log4j, grails-2.0

I have app developed in grails 1.3.x version, i upgraded to 2.0.4, I have a `Log.debug()`  statement and importing `import org.jfree.util.Log` package, When i run the app, its giving me the error.

```
unable to resolve class org.jfree.util.Log grails
```

What is the configuration for log4j after upgrading, how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to log in grails 2.0

```
package org.other

import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

class MyClass { private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(this) … }
```

and then use log.debug(  ... )

see [log guide](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging)